# Given a big list of items with a price and a value, choose the cheapest combination of 10 items with an average value greater or equal to a fixed val

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, combinations

I'm not a computer science major, so I have fairly limited knowledge of algorithms. Lately I was thinking of a market bot of some sort and I have a key question that I cannot handle with brute-force.

```
Question: Let there be a list of items, where number of items are greater
than 10000. Each item has a value in between 0 and 1, and a price. Value and
price are independent of each other. You must choose the cheapest 10 items
where their average (or total) value is greater or equal than a given value.
```

I thought of several algorithms such as:

```
-Sort the list by price
-Divide the list in 5 item chunks, reducing the brute
force steps from 10000nCr10 to 2000nCr2.
```

Obviously it will not give the true cheapest combination, but hopefully close enough? I appreciate any help.

Comment: but what is "close enough" ?

Comment: why would you choose 10 items that make up a certain amount. instead of taking the cheapest? if it is just about reaching a certain amount you should have a look at bin-packing-problems.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina In this case close enough would mean any decent solution that an household CPU (~2GHz) can get in ~5minutes. I know its really vague, but I don't know how to quantify "close enough".

Comment: @PhilippBraun I don't want to get into specific details, but nature of this market forces me to pick only 10 items at a time. So this prevents me of sorting the list with (value/price) and take the cheapest ones.

Comment: You’re going to need to give more details.  “Cheapest” in value or price?  Or with the biggest `value-price`?  You say you can’t sort the list with `value/price`, but one of your attempts is sorting by price.  Could you clarify what you want?

Comment: @Teepeemm In this context cheapest means lowest price. I can sort it by (value/price), but choosing the highest (value/price) ones does not assure that my combination is optimal.

Comment: @Teepeemm Paul Hankins answer to my question describes my question much more accurately, if still confused please see his answer.

Comment: A problem of this kind is called "zero-one assignment". It is a subset of integer programmer as noted by another poster. Searching for zero-one (or 0-1) assignment might help you find specialized methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using integer linear programming. Let the value of item i be v[i] and its cost c[i]. Let x[i] be the number of each item you buy (which can take the values 0 or 1), and V be the minimum acceptable total value. The 0/1 constraint on x[i] makes this an integer linear program rather than a simpler linear program.

Then you want so minimize sum(c[i]*x[i]) such that sum(v[i]*x[i]) >= V and sum(x[i]) = 10, which is a problem of the right form to be solved as an ILP.

Here's a good open-source solver: https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/

Comment: A quick search in wikipedia ends in a very interesting read! Thank you.

Comment: Though I'm not sure how sum(x[i]) = 10 part fits into these types of problems? And without this constraint the problem would not be much different than just sorting the whole list with `value/price` and keep selecting ones until your sum is >=V

Comment: @cozkul Equality constraints are a simple extension to the theory of LP/ILP and most solvers (including GLPK) handle them natively, but in case they don't: sum(x[i]) = 10 is the same as sum(x[i]) <= 10 and sum(x[i]) >= 10. Without the constraint, the solution still isn't the same as the greedy solution of sorting by value/price: for example items with costs 2, 2, 1.1 and values 2, 2, 1 and you want 1 item with value at least 1. Greedy will select one of the items of cost 2 whereas optimal is to choose the item with cost 1.1.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanations. My claim above was a little silly  :) I'll look more into GLPK, and the general problem itself.